# Playing audio broken into multiple files in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, express, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I desire to play an audio-book in my web-page. The audio book is a .zip file, which contains multiple .mp3 files, having one for each chapter of the book. The run time of all the files is several hours, and the their cumulative size is 60MB. The .zip is stored server-side (Express.js)

**How can I play each file in succession in the client (in an `<audio>` element for instance), so that the audio-book plays smoothly, as if 1 file?**

Do I need to use a `MediaStream` object? If so, how?

-Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd take a look at this answer on another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31351186/2444273) however I have made some modifications in order to match your question:

```
var audioFileURLs= [];

function preloadAudio(url) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    // once this file loads, it will call loadedAudio()
    // the file will be kept by the browser as cache
    audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', loadedAudio, false);
    audio.src = url;
}

var loaded = 0;
function loadedAudio() {
    // this will be called every time an audio file is loaded
    // we keep track of the loaded files vs the requested files
    loaded++;
    if (loaded == audioFileURLs.length){
        // all have loaded
        init();
    }
}

var player = document.getElementById('player');
function play(index) {
    player.src = audioFiles[index];
    player.play();
}

function init() {
    // do your stuff here, audio has been loaded
    // for example, play all files one after the other
    var i = 0;
    // once the player ends, play the next one
    player.onended = function() {
        i++;
        if (i >= audioFiles.length) {
            // end 
            return;
        }
        play(i);
    };
    // play the first file
    play(i);
}

// call node/express server to get a list of links we can hit to retrieve each audio file
fetch('/getAudioUrls/#BookNameOrIdHere#')
.then(r => r.json())
.then(arrayOfURLs => {
    audioFileURLs = arrayOfURLs
    arrayOfURLs.map(url => preloadAudio(URL))
})
```

And then just have an audio element on the screen with the id of "player" like `<audio id="player"></audio>`

With this answer though, the `arrayOfURLs` array must contain URLs to an API on your server that will open the zip file and return the specified mp3 data. You may also just want to take this answer as a general reference, and not a complete solution because there is optimization to be done. You should probably only load the first audio file at first, and 5 minutes or so before the first file ends you may want to start pre-loading the next and then repeat this process for the entire thing... That all will be up to you but this should hopefully put you on your feet.

You may also run into an issue with the audio element though because it will only show the length of the current audio segment it is on, and not the full length of the audiobook. I would choose to believe this zip file has the book separated by chapter correct? If so you could create a chapter selector, that pretty much allows you to jump to a specific chapter aka getAudioUrls URL.

I hope this helps!

---

One other note for you... reading your comment on a potential answer down below, you could combine all the audio files into one using some sort of node module ([audioconcat](https://github.com/h2non/audioconcat) is one I found after a quick google search) and return that one file to the client. However, I would not personally take this route because the entire audiobook will be in the server's memory while it combines them, and until it returns it to the client. This could cause some memory issues down the road, so I would avoid it if I could. However, I will admit that this option could be potentially nice because the full length of the audiobook will display in the audio elements timeline.

---

The best option perhaps is to store the books full length and chapter lengths in a details.json file in the zip file and send that to the client in the first API call along with the URLs to each audio file. This would enable you to build a nice UI.

Comment: Definitely the correct solution.  To add to it, there are NPM modules that can extract files out of a ZIP file client-side.  So, if it's convenient to keep everything in that ZIP, you can load the ZIP client-side, extract a blob for the audio as needed, and go from there.

Comment: FYI: The solution described here (https://github.com/qawemlilo/node-streams) can be used to concatenate audio without external modules

Answer (score 0):

The only options I can think of is to use either use a javascript mp3 decoder (or compiled a C decoder to asm.js/wasm) and use the audio APIs. Or wrap the mp3 in an mp4 using something like mux.js and use media source extensions to playback.

Comment: Would a viable option be to merge all the files into one server-side using Expres.js middleware, and then simply use an <audio> element? Would it be reasonable to play such a large/long file in such a way?

Comment: I was under the impression that was not an option. But yes, if you can process server side there are a lot more options. If all the files are encoded that same way, you may be able to simply concatenate them. If not, you can use ffmpeg to concat and convert to a single file and play over http.

Answer (score -3):

maybe this will help you

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="track.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="track.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: That doesn't help at all. I don't think you read the question. Please delete your answer.