# MediaRecorder API simple example / "hello world"

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, web-mediarecorder

Here's a simple example for the MediaRecorder API:

```
(async function() {
  let chunks = [];
  let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio:true, video:false });
  let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

  // record for 3 seconds:
  mediaRecorder.start();
  setTimeout(() => { mediaRecorder.stop(); }, 3000)

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) { chunks.push(e.data); };
  mediaRecorder.onstop = async function() {
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: mediaRecorder.mimeType });
    let audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let arrayBuffer = await (await fetch(audioURL)).arrayBuffer();
    let audioBuffer = await (new AudioContext()).decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
    // ... do stuff with audioBuffer
  };
})();
```

This doesn't currently work in chrome due to a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409402) with the opus codec. It looks like it has been fixed recently so it should reach the stable release within a couple of months (I think?).

So my question is: Is the "hello world" that I've presented above correct? It seems to work fine on firefox, and will hopefully work on chrome soon, but I'm not exactly sure about all the nitty gritty details of the spec and I just want to make sure I'm doing everything right. Some sub-questions regarding the correctness of the example code:

- In Firefox, `mediaRecorder.mimeType` is an empty string and yet the `Blob` is still created successfully apparently. In chrome, `mediaRecorder.mimeType` is "video/webm" even though I specified `video:false` in the `getUserMedia` options. What's going on here?
- Do I need to use `fetch` to convert the blob into an array buffer? It's not hard, but seems a bit hacky.
- Is there a workaround so it works in Chrome while the codec bug is sorted out? I tried `new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType:"audio/wav"});` after reading [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/mimeType), but it gave me a "mimeType not supported" error. In fact, any `mimeType` other than "video/webm" gives an error on chrome, and it seems like firefox is just ignoring the `mimeType` option.
- In the [mdn article on MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) they use `new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });`. Why did they choose that type and codec? How do thay know that's the actual mime type and codec that was used by MediaRecorder? How do they know that mime-type will work in all browsers?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35467995/993683) is a related question/answer. Really, I'd just like some code that I know wont break in 3 months time as things are implemented by browsers and the spec is tweaked. It's be a bonus if it could work with chrome right now too. Thanks!

Comment: For bullet 1, I'd say (though I have no proof) that chrome's implementation is a bit off at the moment. For bullet 2, I'd say the more natural way is to use a FileReader, though I'm not sure about the disadvantages of using fetch here. For bullet 3, a workaround to do what you are currently doing would be to not use the MediaRecorder API at all... You can simply [pass your stream to the AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamSource), and create your arrayBuffer from there. For #4 I guess it's just an example, not necessarily a working one.

Comment: For the extra bullet (something that won't break in 3 months), I guess that almost anything you'll make working today will still work tomorrow. The problem is that today a lot of things don't work the way they should...